# The emulator keeps spinning for ever

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I start the AVD (Target: 3.1) sometimes it never starts (it gets stuck on the screen where it says ANDROID). What should I look for specifically in the ddms.bat log?

It currently seems to contain few logs (seems to be running explicit GC on a regular basis), but I am unable to identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: How well-specced is the machine you're working on? The Honeycomb emulator is very slow, so if you've got an older machine it might just be taking awhile.

Comment: Dell E6400 w/3GB RAM and its quite slow and its very frustrating.

Comment: I'm running a Core i7 at 2.93GHz and it's slow for me too. See if THelper's answer helps you. You can also increase the allotted RAM of your AVD to 1GB since it defaults to 256MB. It may still be slow though. Also, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html#Setup

"Of course, you can also use the Android emulator on your development machine, but because the Android emulator must simulate the ARM instruction set on your computer and the WXGA screen is significantly larger than a typical virtual device, emulator performance is much slower than a real device."

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103736/android-emulator-hanging-on-startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problems with starting an 3.0 AVD in the emulator. What worked for me was setting the emulator's "Max VM application heap" hardware property to 128 (default is 48) and not adding any extra hardware properties.